# How to create array in C++ similar to Python's numpy array?

Tags: python, c++, c++11, numpy

I am converting `Python program to C++` format.

Python has an array in the following format.

```
boxes = np.zeros((1, 300, 4, 5, 1), dtype = np.float)
```

What could be the best way to create a `C++` array functioning similar to that `boxes` array?

Comment: Use an external library. Eigen is an option but there are others.

Comment: Following from what DavidW said, [xtensor](https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor) is a more numpy-like option

Comment: Thanks I'll look into those libraries.

Comment: How is I make a structure with int a, float[] b, float[] c, float[] d, int e contents?

Comment: @batuman Is that a separate question? I'm not that familiar with numpy but that is not equivalent is it? Your original question is about a 1x300x4x5x1 multidimensional array, right?

Comment: If all you need is an array-like structure, I wouldn't look into an external library. That's going to be a lot of time for something that's simple

Comment: @ChrisDrew No I mean, make a structure with multiple arrays.

Comment: @batuman please confirm that you would like to be able to write `x[0][185][3][4][0]`

Comment: Regarding the struct: a struct here would be your dtype. No need for one if you just have doubles.

Comment: @batuman If you don't want a multi-dimensional array I suggest you edit your question to make it clearer because it looks a lot like that at the moment.

Comment: @n.caillou yes I agreed. thank you

Comment: `boxes` is a 4 dimensional array containing 6000 doubles, plus all the class methods provided by `np.ndarray`.  `functioning similar` is a vague requirement.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose is

```
auto boxes = std::array<
                std::array<
                   std::array<
                      std::array<
                         std::array<float, 1U>, 300U>, 4U>, 5U>, 1U> {};
```

or, to avoit the stack overflow problem pointed by Humam Helfawi, you can use `std::vector` (so heap memory) as follows

```
   auto boxes2 = std::vector<
                    std::vector<
                       std::vector<
                          std::vector<
                             std::vector<float>>>>>
                                (1U, std::vector<
                                        std::vector<
                                           std::vector<
                                              std::vector<float>>>>
                                   (300U, std::vector<
                                             std::vector<
                                                std::vector<float>>>
                                      (4U, std::vector<
                                              std::vector<float>>
                                         (5U, std::vector<float>
                                             (1U, 0.0f)))));
```

or, as suggested by n.caillou,

```
using boxA5 = std::array<
                 std::array<
                    std::array<
                       std::array<
                          std::array<float, 1U>, 300U>, 4U>, 5U>, 1U>;

auto boxes3 = std::unique_ptr<boxA5> { new boxA5{} };
```

Comment: I am thinking to make a structure that has int a, float[] b, float[] c, float[] d, int e;

Comment: @HumamHelfawi - thanks; added a `std::vector` solution.

Comment: There's also the obvious `unique_ptr<array<array<...`; much more efficient

Comment: @batuman - sorry; maybe I don't understan pyton but... as far I know you asked a multidimensional array for 1x300x5x4x1 floats

Comment: @n.caillou - it's obvious but I didn't think about it; thanks

Comment: @Swift - sorry but I know C++ much better that Python so ... can you explain how works numpy array different than my C++11 examples?

Answer (score 4):

In fact, numpy allocates a contiguous array storage and the [strides](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) are used to compute memory offset based on a multi-dimensional index. To achieve similar results in C++, you can write something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

class NDArray {
    std::vector<size_t> m_dims, m_strides;
    std::unique_ptr<float[]> m_buf;

    public:
        NDArray(std::vector<size_t> dims):
            m_dims{std::move(dims)}
        {
            m_strides.resize(m_dims.size());
            size_t stride = 1;
            for (int i = m_dims.size() - 1; i >= 0; -- i) {
                m_strides[i] = stride;
                stride *= m_dims[i];
            }
            m_buf.reset(new float[stride]);
        }

        float& operator[] (std::initializer_list<size_t> idx) {
            size_t offset = 0;
            auto stride = m_strides.begin();
            for (auto i: idx) {
                offset += i * *stride;
                ++ stride;
            }
            return m_buf[offset];
        }
};

int main() {
    NDArray arr({2, 3});
    arr[{1, 2}] = 3;
    arr[{1, 1}] = 2;
    printf("%g\n", arr[{1, 2}]);
}
```

Comment: That way also can be mapped or copied to a numpy array, because the API that interfaces C++ and Python would simply return a pointer. But then theer would be raw pointer instead of vector. And if any C++ programmer would say "ew" at the idea, the whole Phyton\C++ API works on raw pointers, no way around it. There is Boost-Python alternative, but it is more sluggish

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>  
vector<vector<vector<vector<double> > > > v;
    v.resize(1);
    v[0].resize(300);
    for(int i=0;i<300;i++)
    {
        v[0][i].resize(4);
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            v[0][i][j].resize(5);
            for(int l=0;l<5;l++)
                v[0][i][j][l]=double(0.0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <vector>

Comment: numpy array is contiguous array and is static as far as I know, not a volatile  tree of vectors